# 403 (Forbidden) while using UrlFetchApp class Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, http-status-code-403, urlfetch

I have a script in GAS that is fetching data from external service.
Everything worked fine till 4th Jan 22, when I started getting 403 error for every request.
The same URL is working fine in Postman by the way

```js
const bbToken = "my_token";
const bbUrl = "https://blackbox.net.ua/api/?data=";

function checkBlackBox() {

  let blackParams = {
    "id": requestId,
    "params": {
      "phonenumber": phone.toString(),
      "api_key": bbToken
    }
  };

  let requestUrl = bbUrl + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(blackParams));

  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(requestUrl);
  let dataPars = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
```

Already tried to whitelist this URL in GAS manifest but didn`t help.

What could be the root-cause and possible ways to fix? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Are you using the Postman local client or the web client? Have you reviewed if there are recent changes to the API that is being called?

Comment: It seems the site has blocked access from Google service because it also gives 403 error with a fetch to you top page `https://blackbox.net.ua/`.